# Using Android device credentials to access critical part of the app

Tags: android, security

How do I show lock screen if user tries to access critical part of my application. I want him to be able to access the critical part only if he can then unlock the device using the device credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a password screen for your application rather then depending on secure lock of android.
Because you can't manage lock screen on all versions of android.

Comment: I want to use the secure lock of android because that ways user would be required to remember only one password.

Comment: There is no SDK API for this, so non-system apps can't really do it.